# Poor performance of virtualization on ubuntu 21.10 (virt-manager)

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

just by switching from 20.04 to 21.10 I get a poor performance on virt-manager, and sometimes it freezes. Just by moving a window around I can see that it lags a lot. I tried many times to move to ubuntu 21.10 and I always get this noticeable difference in the virtualization. I think this has nothing to do with virt-manager but instead with Qemu.

Is there a way to debug what is happening?

UPDATE: the problem is on ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the display driver QXL is not working very well. However, using Virtio + OpenGL acceleration gives a good performance. I think OpenGL acceleration is not needed but it's working very nicely here